# How to know which mailFolder is the Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Calling [`/users/me/mailFolders`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_mailfolders) returns the folders list with their `id`, `displayName`, `parentFolderId`, and some counters.

How can I determine which folder is the "Inbox"?

I cannot use `displayName` because this will probably be in the user's native language. And the `Id` is just a random string.

I need this because my app populates the list of folders and I want to default the "selection" to the Inbox (just like Outlook does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the default folders, you can use a "well-known name" (in this case `inbox`) to get the correct `id`. From [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailfolder):

> Outlook creates certain folders for users by default. Instead of using the corresponding folder **id** value, for convenience, you can use 
>   the following well-known folder names when accessing these folders in a **mailFolder** collection: `ArchiveRoot`, `ConversationHistory`, `DeletedItems`, 
>   `Drafts`, `Inbox`, `JunkEmail`, `Outbox`, and `SentItems`.

To illustrate, calling `/me/mailFolders/inbox` in the sample [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/mailfolders/inbox&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) tenant returns:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAAuAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURAQAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAA=",
    "displayName": "Inbox",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAAuAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURAQAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEIAAA=",
    "childFolderCount": 2,
    "unreadItemCount": 59,
    "totalItemCount": 60
}
```

Comment: Good workaround! Just for note, response can be simplified for this purpose calling `/me/mailFolders/inbox?$select=id`.

Answer (score 4):

In v1.0, I think you'll have to use the localized display names which as you mentioned, can be quite tricky. However, if you use the /beta/ endpoint, you can use the `wellKnownName` property which is a non-localized identifier for a given mailFolder (eg. 'junkemail', 'inbox', etc).